# Analysing functions on zero-length intervals and super-small values

Tags: special-functions, infinitesimals

Suppose a function that has a pole in $x=0$:

[image]

Here we see the graphic of the real part of the Gamma function.

As we can see on it, there is a vertical line at $x=0$ that comes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.
The line is truly vertical, yet we can suppose that it crosses the vertical axis at the height of $-\gamma$.

This is because

$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\Re(\Gamma(ih)+\Gamma(-ih))}2=-\gamma$$

Given this intuition, I have decided to formalize the concept of the behavior of the functions at poles. We can imagine that the line starts at a very tiny negative value of the function's argument, say, $0^-$ with value $\Gamma(0^-)=-\infty$, then grows to take the value $\Gamma(0)=-\gamma$, and then rises to $\Gamma(0+)=+\infty$.

To formalize this, let's stretch this zero-interval $(0^-,0^+)$ to $(-\infty,+\infty)$. To do so, we will look at the values of the function at the nearby complex numbers, where the vertical line is not strictly vertical.

$$f^*(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\Re(f(x  h^2 + i h))$$

[image]

Well, we have amplified this place infinitely and see that indeed, the line crossed the vertical axis with value $-\gamma$.

We can postulate that the value $f^*(1)$ is the value of $f(x)$ at very tiny element $\iota$, and similarly, $f^*(x)=f(x\iota)$. This $\iota$ is not just infinitesimal, it is smaller than any infinitesimals ever. Yet we can evaluate functions at it. Apparently, any function $f(x)$, continuous at zero, will produce constant $f^*(x)$, and a function having simple pole will produce a linear $f^*(x)$. But if the function $f(x)$ behaves more complicatedly at $x=0$, very interesting things can be observed. The limits of $f^*(x)$ will be as follows:

$$\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f^*(x)=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} f(x\iota)=\lim_{x\to\pm 0}f(x)$$

By using the same technique we can see that function $1/x^3$ indeed has 3 poles at zero. By a more complicated approach we will see that for $f(x)=0^x$ $f^*(x)=e^{-\gamma x}$ etc.

Moreover, by analyzing the function $f(1/x)$ we can evaluate the function's behavior at transfinite range (for instance, $1/x$ is $x/\iota$ at super-small range and constant zero at transfinite range from $+\infty$ to $-\infty$).

That said I wonder whether enybody ever analyzed behavior of functions at zero-length intervals in a similar way?

Is there a more universal method of doing so?

Comment: Re-analyzing my finding in the view of G. Edgar's comment makes clear, that I'm just getting the coefficients of the powerseries of the gamma-function and that is the same in the article. So the relation to this current question is thus now at most remote and uninteresting and I'll retract my earlier comment (in the answer-box)